# Xamarin Post request to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, xamarin, http-post

I need some help, I can't send Post request from my android application to ASP.NET Web API, here is the problem :

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #11
03-06 22:47:09.902 D/Mono    (18276): [0xb8afae68] worker starting
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #12
03-06 22:47:09.922 D/Mono    (18276): [0xb8e269a8] worker starting
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #13
03-06 22:47:09.942 D/Mono    (18276): [0xb8ab2948] worker starting
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #14
03-06 22:47:09.952 D/Mono    (18276): [0xb8de5a70] worker starting
03-06 22:47:10.002 D/Mono    (18276): [0xb8afae68] hill climbing, change max     number of threads 5
03-06 22:47:21.292 D/Mono    (18276): [0xb8ab2948] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #13
The thread 'Unknown' (0xd) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

All of the Threads exited with the same code.
I tried to find answer in the Internet but there is nothing that can solve my problem. IIS is working fine, I can see my Web API from mobile browser.

```
btn.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            string msg = title.Text.ToString() + "+" + author.Text.ToString() + "+" + description.Text.ToString();
            string url = "http://192.168.1.13/cadlibrary/";

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

            try
            {
                string jsonData = "{ \"Value\": \"" + msg + "\" }";

                var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Values", content);

                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch(Exception en)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(en.Message);
            }

        };
```

Comment: first, use try/catch to trap the exception

Comment: I see that you posted a log, but did you try to actually catch the exception?

Comment: @Jason yes, first time it was problem with string.Format, then I changed it to this string jsonData, and now there is nothing to see except: The thread 'Unknown' (0xd) has exited with code 0 (0x0).